# skip symfony2 kernel exception

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.8

I am using symfony2.8 and
We have a KernelExceptionService and I want to skip it if there is any Exception like 500,400 or any and get back to service and continue the work.

The reason
We are hitting multiple url to fetch the data and if there is any exception occurred whole processing get stopped.

```
public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event) {
    $exception = $event->getException();
    $response = new JsonResponse;
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if ($exception instanceof InvalidConfigurationException) {
        //500 case
        $responseData = return [
            'code' => Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND,
            'message' => $exception->getMessage()
        ];
    } else {
       // same as aobve if with difference code
    }        

    //Prepare the response
    $response->setData($responseData);
    $response->setStatusCode($statusCode);
    $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the particular code with a try catch block?

That way your exception listener will never trigger and you can handle the exception differently in that specific part of code.

Comment: It tried it but still it hits that logic and no success. I tried with 2 ways. added in controller and added it in service

Comment: can we see the code that runs that causes the exception?

Comment: Oh sorry, Its resolved now. I have use finally. without it it is still it hitting that code. Thanks for help. I am using a service that calls google api using some langitue and longitue but when we pass some garbage data. whole process stops